# Calling runOnUiThread on database handler

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I built a function in database handler to grab data from sqlite + html page using jsoup.
How can i set runOnUiThread to handle data of thread inside a database habdler function?
or How can i attach returned data of thread to Activity from Database Handler file?

files:

-ListInvests.kt > to use DatabaseHandler function to attach data to ListAdapter

-list_invests.xml > is the list items

-startinvest_main.xml > is the view that will show list

DatabaseHandler.kt  (code of thread only)

```
  Thread(Runnable {
                    var init_recent_price=StringBuilder()
                    try{
                        val doc = Jsoup.connect(url_link).get()
                        val table = doc.select("table")[0]
                        val tbody = table.select("tbody")
                        val rows = tbody.select("tr")

                        for (i in rows.indices) {
                            val row = rows[i]//
                            val cols = row.select("td")
                            //karat 21
                            if (i == 2 ) {
                                karat_recent_price = cols[0].text()

                                if(karat_recent_price.contains("إلى")){
                                    var splitter="إلى"
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text

                                }else {
                                    var splitter=" "
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text
                                }
                            }

                            //karat 18
                            if (i == 3 ) {
                                karat_recent_price = cols[0].text()
                                if(karat_recent_price.contains("إلى")){
                                    var splitter="إلى"
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text

                                }else {
                                    var splitter=" "
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text
                                }
                            }

                            //karat 24
                            if (i == 0 ) {
                                karat_recent_price = cols[0].text()

                                if(karat_recent_price.contains("إلى")){
                                    var splitter="إلى"
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text

                                }else {
                                    var splitter=" "
                                    val split_str=karat_recent_price.split(splitter)
                                    karat_recent_price=split_str[0]
                                    init_recent_price.append(karat_recent_price)  //show karat price text
                                }
                            }

                            //inv_amount[index] , inv_enter_price[index] , karat_recent_price
                            var int_amount=amount


                            // new_amount=(int_amount * int_recent_price_string / int_enter_price).toString()
                            new_amount= karat_recent_price
                            catch_new_amount.append(new_amount)


                            if(new_amount > int_amount){
                                var inc=new_amount.toFloat() - int_amount.toFloat()
                                var percent_inc=(inc/int_amount.toFloat())* 100
                                   percent=percent_inc.toString()
                                init_percent_string=percent
                                catch_percent.append(percent)
                            }else {

                                var dec=int_amount.toFloat() - new_amount.toFloat()
                                var percent_dec=(dec/int_amount.toFloat()) * 100
                                percent=percent_dec.toString()
                                init_percent_string=percent
                                catch_percent.append(percent)

                            }



                        }//end for

                    }
                    catch(e: IOException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                 //runOnUiThread  how to set it here?

                }).start()
```

Comment: Direct use of a bare Thread is going to make it difficult to properly cancel the work if your Activity is destroyed while it's still running. I suggest looking into either coroutines (launched from your `viewModelScope`), or at least using Java Executors.

Answer (score 1):

I think its easy.

Assume that you want to update your `textView` in your `activity` then you can update it with this :

First of all we should have an method for define view like this :

```
private lateinit var mView:View

fun initView(view:View) {

    mView = view;
}
```

In your view you should call `initView(this)`

View is an interface like this :

```
interface View{

  }
```

**Finally you can use this :**

```
 mView.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
            mView.updateTextView(yourData)
        })
```

Comment: You should never instantiate an Activity directly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , in MVP structure how can you create a instance of view?!!!

Comment: The OS provides Activity instances when they are requested. Views are instantiated from within the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: How can you pass data from Presenter to View ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 , We want to call a Views method from Presenter , how can you handle it?!!

Comment: I don't like MVP for this reason (I use MVVC), but your View should provide an instance of itself to the Presenter for the Presenter to call back to. A Presenter is not responsible for creating views.

Comment: My main point is that you cannot instantiate a proper Activity yourself. It will not have a proper context, and there is no way to get it on the screen.

Comment: Yes i agree with you .

Comment: I thought this is supposed to be an answer, not a discussion on basic Android fundamentals (Activity being created by the system, and not you). The fact that Activity is treated as "just a View" is already a fundamental misunderstanding of Android, albeit quite popular. Anyways, this answer is conceptually wrong.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , I agree and i am trying to solve it otherwise i delete it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , I update my answer please check it.